# Newton's third law & punching walls

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, conservation-laws, collision

N-law 3: if you punched a wall as hard and as you could, would it possible to retract your hand before the reaction from the wall could affect your hand less than if you wouldn't retract at all?

Newtons third law of physichs/biomechanics/motion (life) basically states "every action has a reaction" right?
I'm a sports student at a university in scandinavia and i'm wondering about the base of newtons reaserch before he decided these rules. I know i probably could try and find a book which could tell me, but i figured this would be a new and a bit more exiting Learning method... And hey, i might actually learn something

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Every action having an opposite and equal reaction makes it impossible to "retract before the reaction", doesn't it? How do you think you can reconcile the two?

Comment: Strictly speaking, "every action has a reaction" is a misstatement of Newton's 3rd Law, because it implies that one of the forces *causes* the other, which is not the case. Drill down deep enough (but not too deep), and all forces come in pairs without a causal connection between them. For example, two charged particles exert equal and opposite electric forces on each other, *full stop*; one force doesn't cause the other; they're just both there.

Comment: By the way, while I understand the sentiment "I know i probably could try and find a book which could tell me, but i figured this would be a new and a bit more exiting Learning method... And hey, i might actually learn something", it's not a good attitude to have (in general, and here in particular). We are not a tutoring service. (Your question is a good one: it focuses on a particular physical concept. I'm just saying that doing your own prior research is expected here, and it's a good habit to be in anyway.)

Comment: What you are "missing" is called Noether's theorem and it links symmetries to conservation laws. That's essentially what Newton's third law is, a somewhat old fashioned way of expressing momentum conservation. Looking into a textbook might be helpful, after all...

Comment: @DuallityZ: Christiaan Huyghens had developed a version of the the action-reaction law for elastic collisions; Newton acknowledges Huyghens, Wren, and others in his writings.  Newton conducted his own experiments -- as he always did -- and  abstracted the conditions in order to arrive at a general law, expressed in terms of forces.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main problem here is the word "reaction". I see two issues:

1. In the context of Newton's 3rd Law, when people refer colloquially to the "reaction", they are referring to the force exerted by the *wall* on the *fist* once it is known that *fist* exerts a force on the *wall*. However, strictly speaking, "every action has an equal and opposite reaction" is a misstatement of Newton's 3rd Law, because it implies that one of the forces *causes* the other, which is not the case. Drill down deep enough (but not *too* deep), and all forces come in pairs (of two equal and opposite forces) without a causal connection between them. For example, two charged particles exert equal and opposite electric forces on each other, *full stop*; one force doesn't cause the other; they're just both *there*.
2. Since "reaction" is *colloquially* synonymous with "effect of the action" or "result of the original action", it is easy to mix things up. In particular, it is easy to see how the "reaction" might be referring to what the *wall* does as a *consequence* of the fist hitting it. Thought about from this perspective, the "reaction" is actually referring to Newton's *2nd* Law, i.e. it is referring to the acceleration that the wall picks up as consequence of the force exerted by the fist. But of course, the resulting acceleration of the wall is in some sense irrelevant to the situation of understanding the forces exerted by the wall and fist on each other: Newton's 3rd Law is *not* referring to the consequences of the dynamics (i.e. what happens to the wall as a consequence of the fist hitting it) but rather to the equal and opposite forces the two objects exert on each other while they are in contact.

In conclusion, "every action has an equal and opposite reaction" is a statement that should no longer be used as a colloquial, every-day language version of Newton's 3rd Law.

Answer (score 1):

No. Newton's thirds law is simultaneous. Once the connection has been made, you cannot undo it. The time parameter has only a forward direction and you cannot go back in time under everyday life conditions. But, don't forget that contact forces are different than forces acting on a distance. Such contact forces that you are considering, take place during a non-zero finite (even though small) interval of time during which the forces you are talking about starts to increase from 0 nonlinearly reaching a maximum and then declining down to zero at the end of the interval. What you feel is the average impact force where it can be thought of as being the area under F(t) vs. t cuve divided by the time interval duration of T. You can do plenty of experiments to change the distribution of F(t) and its maximum height but you cannot avoid Newton's Third Law altogether no matter how fast you act. Sincerely,